# Interpret regression with interaction, total effects or marginal effects?

Tags: regression, interaction, interpretation

I have a question that seems very simple and yet I need a final push to lock up the intuition in my head.

I am running a regression that can be simplified to look like this:

log(wage) = $\beta_0$ + $\beta_1$ Construction + $\beta_2 $ Union + $\beta_3 $ Construction*Union

(where Construction and Union are dummy variables).

I want to study the effect of joining a union on construction workers' wages. I want to understand how I should be interpreting the following differently:

Method 1:

(log(wage) when Construction = 1 & Union = 1) - (log(wage) when Construction = 1 and Union = 0) =

( $\beta_0 + \beta_1 + \beta_2 + \beta_3 $) - ($\beta_0 + \beta_1$) = $ \beta_2 + \beta_3 $

Method 2:

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial Union} \left( \dfrac{\partial log(wage)}{\partial Construction} \right)$ = $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial Union} (\beta_1 + \beta_3 Union )$ = $\beta_3 $

I understand that in method 2, I am seeing how the marginal effect of being a construction worker varies with being in a union. And in method 1, I am saying, conditional on being a construction worker, what is the gain/loss from being in a union. I am also measuring total effects (am I right?) in method 1. But here is the part I am having trouble getting my mind around -- if $\beta_2$ is part of the boost/loss a construction worker incurs from being in a union (as in method 1), then why should it not be part of how the marginal effect of being a construction worker varies with being in a union? I understand the math shows it, but please help me get my intuition right. What is the difference in the questions that each method answers? When should each be used?

Comment: What can I do to encourage answers? The question has been posted for a while? Is the question unclear?